# Symfony 2 form builder custom options available in twig

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig

I would like to do something like this:

```
$builder->add('firstname', 'text', array(
                    'myCustomOption' => 'optionValue'
                ));
```

so I can use `myCustomOption` in myForm.html.twig like this:

```
{% block form_row -%}
    {{ myCustomOption }}
{%- endblock form_row %}
```

But in this case I get:

> The option "myCustomOption" does not exist. Known options are: [..]

Comment: When I want to add custom attributes, I put them in the [`attr` array](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#attr), so that in the twig template I can use `attr.myCustomOption`.

Comment: hmm. But you can pass only scalar values like that, and they will be displayed in html. Passing array will throw: `An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Array to string conversion") in form_div_layout.html.twig at line 326. `

Comment: If it's an array, you have to iterate over it with a `for` loop, you can't just try to echo it as a string. Twig has a [dump](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/dump.html) function if you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer: **Type Extension**

It allow to extend desired form type `email/phone/checkbox` or group `text/entity/choice` or even all available `form`.
*(Remember that one element can contain few types. For example input `email` will be type of `form, text, email`)*

**Just create extension class:**

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractTypeExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class TextTypeExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension {

    public function getExtendedType() {
        return 'form'; // What type should be extended
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
        // Add optional option - you can also add required options
        // and available values of this option
        $resolver->setOptional(array('myOption'));
    }

     public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options) {
        // You can put any logic here
        // For example 'myOption' => 'big' can be transformed to 
        // 'myOption' => '300px'
        if (array_key_exists('myOption', $options)) {
            // Add your option to twig template
            $view->vars['myOption'] = $options['myOption'];
        }
    }

}
```

**add class as service:**

```
services:
    acme_demo_bundle.image_type_extension:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\Form\Extension\TextTypeExtension
        tags:
            - { name: form.type_extension, alias: form }
```

**and now you can do:**

```
$builder->add('MyInput', 'text', array('myOption' => array('whateverYouNeed')));
```

**Source:**
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_form_type_extension.html

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
class MyTextType extends AbstractType
{

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'text';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'my_text';
    }

    ....

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver
            ->setDefaults([
                'myOption' => null
            ])
        ;
    }    

    ....
}
```

service definition:

```
acme_demo_bundle.text_type:
    class: Acme\DemoBundle\Form\Type\MyTextType
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: my_text }
```

usage:

```
$builder->add('someName', 'my_text', ['myOption' => $value])
```

Comment: And you want me to do tones of private custom element classes for each element available? Text, Select, Entity and whatever is there?
http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types.html

Comment: @imclickingmaniac This is just an example. It's up to you how to implement it.

Comment: Right. Tell me how I can implement that to all existing form types. So I can use: `$builder->add('anyName', 'anyTypeHere', array('myOption' => array()));`